# How can I separate a filename from folders in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I separate a filename from a folder in a string in ActionScript? It should split the variable and save it in two separate variables that I can use later on.

I guess I'd have to use a regex but I'm not that good at regexes.

For example:

```
var filepath = "/Users/folder1/folder2/test.zip";
```

How can I separate it into this?:

```
 var filename = "test.zip";
 var path = "/Users/folder1/folder2/";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-regex approach could be something like this:

```
var fullpath:String = "/Users/folder1/folder2/test.zip";
var arr:Array = fullpath.split("/");
var filename:String = arr.pop();
var path:String = arr.join("/") + "/";

trace(filename); // outputs test.zip
trace(path); // outputs /Users/folder1/folder2/
```

Answer (score 0):

Or without an Array :

```
var fullpath:String = "/Users/folder1/folder2/test.zip";
var filename:String = fullpath.substr(fullpath.lastIndexOf("/")+1,fullpath.length);
var filepath:String = fullpath.substr(0,fullpath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
trace("filename = " + filename);
trace("filepath = " + filepath);
trace("fullpath = " + fullpath);

/*
filename = test.zip
filepath = /Users/folder1/folder2/
fullpath = /Users/folder1/folder2/test.zip
*/
```